# How to find full path to a folder without it's full name

Tags: powershell

I have a folder to which I have the path to, lets say C:/Users/Me/Project

Inside the Project folder there are 2 or more folders and one of them has a certain word like data1-latest. Only one folder inside Project has the word "latest" in it. The words before "latest" are unknown/random. How can I get the full path to data1-latest while only knowing it contains the word "latest" in it's name? I know I can use **"cd C:/Users/Me/Project/*/specific folder that exists only here"** but I would like to store the path to this folder inside a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
$fullPath = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath C:/Users/Me/Project -Filter *latest -Directory).FullName
```

- Using `-LiteralPath` so PowerShell doesn't try to interpret it as a wildcard path. When using `-Path` instead, PowerShell applies its own [extended wildcard syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2) like `[a-z]`, which sometimes comes as a surprise when a path contains literal `[` and `]` characters.
- `-Directory` makes sure we only get directories
- `-Filter` filters the directories using the wildcard syntax supported by the filesystem provider
- `.FullName` gets a property from the [`FileSystemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=net-6.0) class, which is the common base class for both [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-6.0) and [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0), outputted by `Get-ChildItem`.
- To make sure you have found exactly one directory matching `*latest`, you may check the `Count` property:

  ```sh
  if( $fullPath.Count -ne 1 ) { 
      Write-Error 'Could not find exactly ONE directory matching *latest.' 
  }
  ```